# Ajax / PHP / MySQL: Inserting data into db not working with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, insert, insert-into

I am new to PHP and MySQL and am looking for help with the following.

**I would like to store a users email and selected language in a db on button click**.
My thought was I could use Ajax for this so I put the below Ajax call in my JS functions file to pass the data to a separate Ajax file (`ajax.php`) which then inserts it into the db ("`Users`").

When I alert the values in JS they show correct so my input variables are ok and also the Ajax call returns "`success`" after passing the data but **I can't get this to insert anything in my db**.
When I run the same INSERT manually in the db it works fine.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

**My Ajax call (in my functions file):**

```
$('#btnID').on('click', function(){
    var email = $.trim( $('#email').val() ).toLowerCase();
    var lang = $.trim( $('#lang').val() );

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        cache: "false",
        data: {
            email: email,
            lang: lang
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
```

**My PHP (in my ajax.php file):**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$lang = $_POST["lang"]; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, lang) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $lang . "')";
$conn->close();
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just preparing the query and not triggering it

```
$conn->query($sql)
```

So, You should have something like

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$lang = $_POST["lang"]; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, lang) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $lang . "')";
if ($conn->query($sql)) 
{ 
echo 'success'; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo 'failure'; 
}
$conn->close();
```

**Warning :**

1. You're not [sanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129677/3282633) your input (Never trust your input)
2. You shall prefer [Prepared statements PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to make it better

**Update :**

As the OP needs to know more about cleaning the input

There are severals steps or approaches available

1. If you are getting the integer as input then make it as integer.

> ```
> $id = $_GET['id'];
> settype($id, 'integer');
> ```

2. Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for escaping function for query variables
3. Use [strip_tags()](https://php.net/strip_tags) to remove the unwanted unwanted html
4. If you have embeddedstring then do [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
5. Input might be shellcommand to burst everything [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works great ! Can you explain what you mean by "cleaning" ?

Comment: You're welcome .. It means sanitizing. You can do it by [escaping](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) , [filtering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) etc.,

Comment: Thanks - I thought the $.trim would be enough here ? I just started programming, could you maybe give me some examples or typical approach for this ? I do validate the email input separately when submitting this (just didn't add this here).

Comment: Got it - thanks a lot, this is great and really helpful ! Will definitely apply and will accept the answer as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Welcome. +1 for your eagerness about cleaning input :)

Comment: Thanks. I thought if I learn it I better start right from the beginning. :)

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry, I thought this was working but was looking at the wrong things. It seems it still doesn't do the Insert. Is there anything else that could be missing here, maybe on the SQL side ?

Comment: Its okay, Can you do `echo $sql` and put it inside phpmyadmin and see what happens ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am really sorry. I have the PHP saved in a separate file called ajax.php. Currently there is nothing else in there as this is for testing. Where would I echo the $sql then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81114/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-keewee279).

Comment: As discussed through the chat his is now working with your updated solutions - thanks so much for that !

Comment: You're welcome, Also don't forget to remove the alert in the ajax function:) Because it will print or alert the query or success everytime

Comment: Sure - will do that. :)

Comment: Sure do, If you got it trouble you shall ping me any time ;)

Comment: I will definitely do that - thanks again for all your help ! I am sure I will stumble across the next question some time soon. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually inserting anything. For that, you need to call `$conn->query($sql)` after building your SQL.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$lang = $_POST["lang"]; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, lang) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" .      $lang . "')";
$conn->query($sql); //check the return value here and do what you want
$conn->close();
```